# How do I pass the C # Selenium Error Page?

Tags: c#, webdriver

I'm writing a bot with `c # selenium`. (The working logic of the bot is simply that there are *20 companies* on each page, they go back to the detail page and get the data back. They go through all the companies in order. After getting the data of the last company, they continue to the next page.) After visiting 200-250 companies, the page in the picture opens. Bot's stopping progress. If I press the `F5` menu manually, the bot continues to progress, but it doesn't work when we try with the code.

How do I resolve this error?

[Error Page](https://ibb.co/2yr06tP)

I noticed it was on the way back from the detail page of this page. To go back;

```
driver.navigate().Back();
driver.navigate().GoToUrl("");

//I tried to go back with the codes but the solution was not.
```

I get [this Error](https://ibb.co/LR94y8R) because the error page does not pass.

Bot needs to visit all companies without encountering an error page.

Comment: When I caught the error, closing the chrome driver and turning it back on provided me a solution.

Answer (score 0):

A correct approach for this is to wait for some amount of time for some element you expect on the page using `WebDriverWait`.
In this example, I wait for 10 seconds and look for element id `'some-id'`.
You can change the criteria by replacing `By.Id("some-id")` with some other condition.

More about `By` [class](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/T_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_PageObjects_ByAll.htm).

```
var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));

driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.somedomain.com");

var validPage = false;
try
{
    validPage = wait.Until(c =>
    {
        try
        {
            return driver.FindElement(By.Id("some-id")) != null;
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
    });
}
catch
{
    // not exist
}

if (validPage == true)
{
    // ok.
}
else
{

}
```

Comment: When I caught the error, closing the chrome driver and turning it back on provided me a solution.